# Redirect requests for images from one server to another using Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

We ported application code from one server to another, but the clients still reference the old server. We're on Rails 3.2.12 for both servers.

How do we redirect image requests from the old server to the new server? Specifically, all images requested under directory Y, i.e., `http://www.oldhost.com/images/Y/back.png => http://www.newhost.com/images/Y/back.png`

We have tried this inside of `routes.rb`, and it fails to redirect, meaning image requests still get served by oldhost.com: match '/images/Y/*img_path' => redirect( host: 'newhost.com', :status => 302 )

Comment: It is better to rewrite the URL at web server level, so that url doesnt go through the rails stack. Which web server are you using Apache or nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this on Oldhost.com:-

```
rewrite "/images/Y/([a-zA-z0-9\.]+)" http://www.newhost.com/images/Y/$1
```

With Rails, something like this should work

add route in routes.rb

```
get '/images/Y/:name', to: redirect('http://www.newhost.com/images/Y/%{name}')
```

OR

add route in routes.rb

```
match '/images/Y/:name', :to => "serve_images#send"
```

Create controller serve_images_controller.rb

```
def send
redirect_to "http://www.newhost.com/images/Y/#{params[:name]}"
end
```

Comment: No, on olhost.com nginx configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. Dont forget to restart the server and update regex above accordingly.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to do it within routes.rb? these requests are infrequent and we may port the app to another server and IP (same domain, though). if we keep it in routes.rb, it'll be easier to port than having to remember to update whatever web server we're using on the new machine.

Comment: I just mentioned, we would like to do that so that URL does not have to go through the rails stack and it is redirected from Web server itself. In case you do it with routes, you have to keep running whole lot of application there as well, which is not recommended if you are porting.

Comment: parts of rails are still running, just not the code for this one app. hence, we still need rails to run. how can we do this through routes? thanks again!

Comment: can't you just do the redirect inside routes like we have in our question (just edited to show what we have tried in the past)?

Comment: Yeah, you can do that too. Updated my answer

Comment: as we mentioned in the question, we tried "match '/images/Y/*img_path' => redirect( host: 'newhost.com', :status => 302 )" but it failed to redirect ... any clues why?